# Exception handling for 'readFile'

Tags: haskell, file-io, error-handling, handler

I'm trying to add a simple handler to the `readFile` function:

```
readHandler :: IOError -> IO ()  
readHandler e  
    | isDoesNotExistError e = putStrLn "The file does not exist"
    | otherwise = putStrLn "Something went wrong"  

main = do
    // stop executing if there is no file   
    contents <- (readFile "path.xml") `catch` readHandler
    // generates [(x,y),(x,y)]
    coordinates = parseXML contents
    // I want to do something with the coordinates
    nextFunction coordinates
```

When I try to compile this I get the error:

```
Couldn't match type `()' with `[Char]'
Expected type: IOError -> IO String
  Actual type: IOError -> IO ()
In the second argument of `catch', namely `readHandler'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  contents <- (readFile "path") `catch` readHandler
In the expression:
  do { contents <- (readFile "path") `catch` readHandler;
       putStrLn contents }
```

Thus `readHandler :: IOError -> IO ()` should be `readHandler :: IOError -> IO String`.

But this way I can't print the error message.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What should the type of `catch (readFile "path") readHandler` be?

Obviously if the file exists, we'd want it to be a `String`, `catch` shouldn't change it's type, so somehow we have to produce a `String` no matter what. Since if an exception is thrown, `readHandler` is run, it must also produce a string.

In this way `catch` is acting like a very sophisticated `if` expression :) However, it's less than ideal since we don't want to keep running our function with some random `String` that didn't come from the file.

Instead we could do something like

```
 main = handle readHandler $ do
    ...
```

Since now we just have to produce an `IO ()`, trivial.

If this doesn't float your boat for whatever reason, another sane choice would be to transform that irritating exception to a more pleasant `Either`

```
 main = do
   strOrExc <- try $ readFile "foo"
   case strOrExc of
     Left except -> print except
     Right contents -> putStrLn contents
```

and of course you could handle this `Exception e => Either e a` in whatever way brings you happiness.

There is of course a final alternative, bring the whole program to a screeching halt right then and there. We can do this just by changing `readHandler`

```
import System.Exit

readHandler :: IOError -> IO a
readHandler = putStrLn "Buckle your seatbelts" >> exitFailure
```

Comment: I edited my code to be more clear. Is there a way to use your second solution with my handler, and continue my execution chain if the file is found?

Comment: @Gert-Jan Sure, instead of just printing the string, put whatever you intend to use the string for in that case branch. This is of course ugly. A not unreasonable approach is the `Either` monad.

Comment: Now the problem is that 'strOrExc' is of type 'Either a0 String" instead of 'String'. I think my knowledge for Haskell isn't good enough to solve this problem yet. Thanks for the help tough! :)

Comment: @Gert-Jan Of course, the problem is that you have "Either" an exception or a `string`, that `case` thing let's you pattern match and get access to the `String`, in my example, it's called contents

Comment: And now i'm getting 'No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of 'print'' (and a few other errors). I'm going to stop here and maybe try again tomorrow.. I'm sure your answer is correct and I thank you for your help!

Comment: Solved it! One last question maybe, is it possible to declare a variable that holds a string in the 'Right' part and use it after the Case?

Comment: @Gert-Jan No, since it would violate lexical scope

Answer (score 2):

catch has type

```
catch :: Exception e => IO a -> (e -> IO a) -> IO a
```

So if the first parameter of catch is `IO String`, then the second argument (which is a function), has to return that either. 
You could change your readHandler like so:

```
readHandler :: IOError -> IO String
readHandler e  
    | isDoesNotExistError e = do putStrLn "The file does not exist" ; return ""
    | otherwise = do putStrLn "Something went wrong" ; return ""
```

But I am not sure, whether that's a wanted "side effect" (returning an empty string).

Comment: This works, but I need the program to stop and not return an empty String. There has to be a better way I think.